# Python passing thread reference to logging LogHandler module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module to setup my logging where I am defining a LogHandler. In this LogHandler I want to pass the message to a function in a thread created from my main python file (The one which included my logging module). I found that I can pass the thread reference to my logging module (id needed) but I cannot figure out how to make it accessible by the LogHandler callback.

Here is what it looks like:

```
main.py
import WebSocket
import Log

wsthread = WebSocket()
wsthread.start() # thread manages websocket connection which can pipe data to 

Log.setup() # I could pass thread here if needed

WebSocket.py
class WebSocket (threading.Thread):  
    def send(self, msg):
        #send msg to websocket

Log.py
class Log():
    @staticmethod
    def setup(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger("testlogger")
        handler = LogHandler()
        logger.addHandler(handler)

class LogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        # i want to send the 'record' txt to wsthread.send(self.format(record))
```

What is the correct paradigm to solve this in python?